# MYSQL - Select Only Records Where Previous Record Column Data Differs

Tags: mysql, sql

Hoping this is possible with just sql. I have a query that returns a data set with time_stamp and hash_index columns. Basically something to the effect of:

```
1   1583365548  6ff11ad5536f28d66098f6d74f97d877
2   1583365554  6ff11ad5536f28d66098f6d74f97d877
3   1583365556  6ff11ad5536f28d66098f6d74f97d877
4   1583365562  a2e99acb2540d49955ef93fb2684ac25
5   1583365571  a2e99acb2540d49955ef93fb2684ac25
6   1583365572  a2e99acb2540d49955ef93fb2684ac25
7   1583365574  a2e99acb2540d49955ef93fb2684ac25
8   1583365578  a2e99acb2540d49955ef93fb2684ac25
9   1583365580  a2e99acb2540d49955ef93fb2684ac25
```

What I want to do is further filter this query to only include the record if the hash_index differs from the previous record. Is this something I can do without having to dump it into PHP and loop through it?

My current query is below:

```
SELECT 
    (@cnt:=@cnt + 1) AS row_number,
    time_stamp,
    MD5(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(user_state_name,
                        option_id,
                        option_code,
                        item_id,
                        item_code))) AS hash_index
FROM
    user_state
WHERE
    user_id = 2
GROUP BY
    time_stamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is with a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM user_state t1
LEFT JOIN user_state t2 ON t1.id-1 = t2.id
WHERE t1.hash_index <> t2.hash_index;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out adjacent duplicates, I would just use `lag()` and dispense with hashing and aggregation:

```
SELECT us.*
FROM (SELECT us.*,
             LAG(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time_stamp) as prev_ts,
             LAG(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, user_state_nae, option_id, option_code, item_id, item_code ORDER BY time_stamp) as prev_ts_values
      FROM user_state us
      WHERE user_id = 2
     ) t
WHERE prev_ts_values is null or prev_ts_values <> prev_ts;
```

You can select whichever rows you want.